# Linking of CUDA library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker-errors

I am using CMake 3.10 and have a problem linking a compiled library to a test executable in CMake.
I searched a lot and found that in earlier versions there was a problem where you could not link intermediate libraries in the result executable. I was not able to tell if this was resolved or still an issue.

My CMake files look like this:

Algo:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)
project(${MODULE_NAME}_core LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)


add_subdirectory("${core_impl_dir}" implementation)


set(cuda_src "parallel/ParallelComputation.cu")
set(cuda_hdr "parallel/ParallelComputation.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC "${cuda_src}" "${cuda_hdr}"
)


target_include_directories (${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "include/" 
"parallel/"
)

source_group("parallel"  FILES "${cuda_src}" "${cuda_hdr}")


set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER ${MODULE_NAME})
```

Test:

```
project(${MODULE_NAME}_gtest LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_subdirectory("${gtest_impl_dir}" implementation)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "${gtest_impl_src}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MODULE_NAME}_core)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories("${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}")


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})

source_group("Implementation\\Source Files" FILES "${gtest_impl_src}" )

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER ${MODULE_NAME})

add_test(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Building just Algo works fine, but when also building Test, I get linking errors, for example

> ../implementation/libmatrix1_testCuda_core.a(ParallelComputation.cu.o): In Funktion 'cudaError cudaMalloc(float**, unsigned long)':
>   tmpxft_00005ad0_00000000-5_ParallelComputation.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4f2): Undefined reference 'cudaMalloc'

EDIT
using `make VERBOSE=1` I got this linking command:

> /usr/bin/c++  -Wl,--no-as-needed -pthread -g -std=c++14 -Wall
>   CMakeFiles/matrix1_testCuda_gtest.dir//tests/eclipseProject/algos/testCuda/test/src/main.cpp.o
>   CMakeFiles/matrix1_testCuda_gtest.dir/cmake_device_link.o  -o
>   matrix1_testCuda_gtest ../implementation/libmatrix1_testCuda_core.a
>   /usr/lib/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a

Comment: The root cause is probably not linking the CUDA runtime library. If nvcc was doing the linking, that would not be necessary, which suggests that your host compiler is doing the linking. How you fix it in CMake, I have no idea

Comment: @talonmies I got the CUDA runtime problem to work by using find_package(CUDA 9.0 REQUIRED), or by setting the linker language explicitly to CUDA. Now the linker complains about the device code. What I don't understand here is that the device code is only called in the library, the main test code only imports an interface that exposes normal C++ methods which in turn call device code. Why does it even need linking here, shouldn't the linking of the device code already be done in the step that builds the library?

Comment: @talonmies never mind that last one was actually my mistake, the namespace in the header and the implementation did not match, and the compiler did not catch it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer is for CMake versions < 3.10. The method shown here is deprecated since CMake 3.10 but should in principle still work for newer versions. It's what I ended up using with CMake 3.10.

For CMake version >= 3.10 but < 3.17, check first if Pat Lorton's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57170448/1319284) helps.

For CMake 3.17+, check VojtaK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74853904/1319284).

---

I got this to work by calling

```
find_package(CUDA 9.0 REQUIRED)
```

in both CMake files.
Also, in the Algo file (which contains the device code), I had to do

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

I was expecting that the language support for CUDA would make those steps unnecessary, but apparently not.

Comment: This is no longer the idiomatic soluion in newer CMake versions.

Comment: @einpoklum Since this seems a question that is viewed by many people, if this is different for newer CMake versions, please add an answer with the new method.

Comment: @kutschkem Maybe you want to point out VojtaK's answer that shows the usage of [FindCUDAToolkit](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) which imports the different libraries as targets. Worked like a charm for me and seems to be a more modern or idiomatic solution.

Comment: @SimonH How can I best do that?

Comment: @kutschkem I don't know what would be the best way, if there is any, but you could edit your answer saying that for cmake 3.17+, if a program does not contain CUDA code but shall only be linked against CUDA libraries, `FindCUDAToolkit` perfectly suits that use case (referencing VojtaK's answer). You can leave your solution using `FindCUDA` there for people who use an older cmake version for whatever reason, but even the cmake documentation states `FindCUDA` [is deprecated since cmake 3.10](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html).

Comment: @SimonH Edit good like that?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into something very similar to this where the root problem was that most of my binary was being compiled with my system cxx compiler, and the cuda bits were being compiled with the cuda gcc compiler (9.1 for system, 8.3 for cuda).

Surprisingly it was fixed by changing:

`project(MyProject LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)`

to

`project(MyProject LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)`

After that change, CMake picked up the cuda version of the gcc compiler as the main compiler, and my binary started building again.  I'm not sure if this could introduce problems for other packages, but it fixed the linking problem I was hitting.

Comment: I had a working project and then it fails to compile with CUDA. Similar error. Same solution.

Comment: Personally, I have an issue where it doesn't link the CUDA library unless I specify it explicitly...

Answer (score 7):

Adding the possible way in CMake 3.17 and further

When you wish not to include any CUDA code, but e.g. using only calls to cufft from `C++` it is sufficient to do the following

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit)
target_link_libraries(project CUDA::cudart)
target_link_libraries(project CUDA::cufft)
```

If you are however enabling CUDA support, unless you want to get into troubles call it after enabling CUDA.

```
include(CheckLanguage)
check_language(CUDA)
if(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
enable_language(CUDA)
find_package(CUDAToolkit)
target_link_libraries(project CUDA::cudart)
target_link_libraries(project CUDA::cuda_driver)
else()
message(STATUS "No CUDA compiler found")
endif()
```

Because CUDAToolkit [respects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) enable CUDA runtime added but it does not work vice versa.

Note that some CUDA versions do not work with too recent GCC compiler. So when e.g. CUDA 11.3 and GCC 12 are installed, `check_language(CUDA)` won't be able to find CUDA, as it needs GCC 10 or lower. You just get CUDA not found and an only solution is to downgrade GCC in that situation.

Comment: [FindCUDAToolkit](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) is supported as of cmake 3.17, not 3.18, isn't it? This is the real answer, at least for people not sticking to an medieval version of cmake for whatever reasons.

Comment: I was trying it in 3.18 but it can make in 3.17 as well. Thanks, changed it.